# What do you call the property of having two separate groups that make a whole?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call two non-overlapping (i.e., mutually exclusive) groups that compose a whole?

Two examples:

1. Men and women  (together = all humans)
2. Age ≥ 60 yrs. and age < 60 yrs.  (together = individuals of all ages)

How can this property be expressed?

Comment: In maths jargon, those are (binary) [set partitionings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set).

Comment: I'm unclear from your question (particularly since the edit) whether you are looking for the word to indicate that the groups make up the entire whole?  If so, then **exhaustive** seems appropriate.

Comment: Although neither are very common *bifurcate* and *bifurcal* are both adjectives that could describe the whole. *Bifurcate* is much more common as a verb.

Answer (score 1):

[Complement:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/complement)

either of two parts or things needed to complete the whole; counterpart.

Comment: Yes, "complement" if you're talking set theory and thus "complementary" if you're looking at English. jckim, don't you think that's as likely to happen as your explanation is to be clear without the mathematical symbols? Ie, to me, the question isn't about English.

Answer (score 0):

'Mutually exclusive' sounds more natural than 'non-overlapping', but I would be inclined to say the (entire) group was "divided into two'.